# Doctrine QueryBuilder "andWhere" query

Tags: doctrine, where-clause

I am using this code:

```
        $queryBuilder
            ->add('select', 'd.type')
            ->add('from', 'Entities:TypeDetail d')
            ->add('where', 'IDENTITY(d.typeName) = ' . $typeName->getId())
            ->add('andWhere', 'd.dateValue > ' . $dates['start'])
            ->add('andWhere', 'd.dateValue < ' . $dates['end']);
```

But I get this error: `Notice: Undefined index: andWhere in...`

I figure "andWhere" is not the correct name to use, but everywhere I read online suggests it is. But that is using the form `->andWhere()`, not using `->add()` like I am.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this? -

```
$queryBuilder
        ->add('select', 'd.type')
        ->add('from', 'Entities:TypeDetail d')
        ->add('where', $queryBuilder->expr()->andx(
             $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('IDENTITY(d.typeName)', $typeName->getId()),
             $queryBuilder->expr()->gt('d.dateValue', $dates['start']),
             $queryBuilder->expr()->lt('d.dateValue', $dates['end'])
        ));
```

Links here -

[Doctrine Query Builder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class)

Comment: Where does `$qb` come from? Should that also be the `$queryBuilder` object?